# "Get along", "Compromise", "Put up" and "Cope with"

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I wonder which choice works in my sentence and which one doesn't and why?

> - I never forget the time Sam fought the BBC's reporter when he offended Sam by saying those words! I think as a diplomat, he has to be able to ......... annoying remarks.

**1. Put up with**

> To accept or continue to accept an unpleasant situation or experience, or someone who behaves unpleasantly: 
> **Example:** I can put up with the house being messy, but I hate it if it's not clean.

**2. Cope with:**

> To deal successfully with a difficult situation: 
> **Example:** It must be really hard to cope with three young children and a job.

**3. Get along with:**

> To deal with a situation, usually successfully: 
> **Example:** I wonder how Michael is getting along in his new job?

**4. Compromise with**

> Compromise as a noun means: a situation in which people accept something slightly different from what they really want, because of circumstances or because they are considering the wishes of other people. 
> [This meaning fits well with my needed concept; but dictionaries did not provide me with a similar meaning in verbal form of the word "compromise" and it was why I just brought up the noun form meaning.]

So as you see, it was why I thought all the listed options  above work in this specific case! But I don't know (if I am correct,) how each phrasal verb changes the meaning of my scenario. It is sort of a question that really gets me often into trouble. I wonder if you could help me with it.

Comment: I would suggest *he has to be able to **ignore** annoying remarks*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Getting along" does not fit. In fact, even your example is wrong. It should be "I wonder how Michael is getting *on* in his new job", although some people do seem to mix up these two idioms. "Getting along" usually refers to a relationship between two people.

"Compromise"  means a trade-off between two things and can sometimes be an agreement to settle somewhere in the middle or for a third option which takes in at least some of the other two options. In your statement, there is no trade-off - just one thing you can bear and another thing you can't - so this is not appropriate either.

Idiomatically, options 1 and 2 are both fine in context. People *do* say these. There is a difference in their meaning.

"Cope with" means that you *can handle* something. It doesn't necessarily infer that those things are bad. For example:

> My wife copes with being a businesswoman and a mother.

So, saying that you can "cope with a messy house" doesn't necessarily mean that you dislike it.

"Put up with" means to *tolerate* something, so this *does* imply that it is something you normally dislike or disagree with yet do not interfere with or attempt to stop. For example:

> My wife puts up with my bad habits.

I would say then that the most appropriate expression in your sentence is "*put up with*" (or simply "tolerate"?) because that best implies that "messy" is something you dislike, but "dirty" is where you draw the line and will *not* tolerate it.